# Execute ASP in Mono

Tags: asp.net, apache, iis, mono

I have an IIS server that I would like to convert to Apache in Windows.

I have installed `Httpd-2.4.6-x86` and I have successfully brought up the test page.  Because I am running ASP on IIS, I installed `mono-3.2.3-gtksharp-2.12.11-win32-0`.  I don't know how to test it.

When I installed Apache I put it into the default folder: `C:\Apache24`.  My IIS server root is in `C:\MyDocuments2\Web`

I made these changes to httpd.conf:

```
DocumentRoot "C:\MyDocuments2\Web"
<Directory "C:\MyDocuments2\Web">
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html default.asp
</IfModule>
```

I stopped the server and re-started it.  When I go to my web page, it displays the file default.asp.  What do I need to do to *execute* default.asp?

Comment: Why would you run Apache on a Windows machine, to then run Asp.Net?

Comment: I have run a few web sites in iis for years.  I would like to start creating web pages with Wordpress. I have a windows machine that is running 24hrs a day.  I need it running to support the iis web pages.  I'd like to run all web sites at the same time.  Thanks, Docfxit

Comment: Wordpress runs fine on IIS (just install the PHP extension), so your statement makes no sense to me.

Comment: WordPress and PHP are first class citizens on Windows. You're making a rod for your own back.

Comment: As a side note: please stop signing everything (questions, answers, comments).  There is no need for you to type a signature on Stack Overflow, as your username / link to your profile directly follows everything you post (automatically).  See the community guidelines on meta: [Are taglines & signatures disallowed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed)

Comment: Post this question to Server Fault.  SO is for programming questions.

Answer (score 2):

Mono doesn't implement ASP (.asp), it implements ASP.NET (.aspx).